# Status not shown label in admin grid in magento 2

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

> shippingbar_post_listing.xml

```
<column name="status">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options" xsi:type="object">CM\Shippingbar\Model\Status</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Status</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
```

> CM\Shippingbar\Model\Status.php

```
  <?php

namespace CM\Shippingbar\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface;

/**
 * ProductStatus Class
 */
class Status implements OptionSourceInterface
{
 /**
     * @var \CM\Shippingbar\Model\Productlabel
     */
    protected $model;


    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \CM\Shippingbar\Model\ModelFile $model
     */
   protected function _construct(\CM\Shippingbar\Model\Shippingbar $model)
    {
$this->model = $model;   
 }

    /**
     * Get options
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $options[] = ['label' => '', 'value' => ''];
        $availableOptions =$this->model->getAvailableStatuses();
        foreach ($availableOptions as $key => $value) {
            $options[] = [
                'label' => $value,
                'value' => $key,
            ];
        }
        return $options;
    }

}
```

> CM\Shippingbar\Model\Shippingbar.php

```
 <?php
namespace CM\Shippingbar\Model;

class Shippingbar  extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel 
{
    const STATUS_ENABLED = 1;
    const STATUS_DISABLED = 0;



    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('CM\Shippingbar\Model\ResourceModel\Shippingbar');
    }


     public function getAvailableStatuses()
    {
        return [self::STATUS_ENABLED => __('Enabled'), self::STATUS_DISABLED => __('Disabled')];
    }
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> In **shippingbar_post_listing.xml** file.

```
<column name="status">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">CM\Shippingbar\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Status</item><item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">60</item>
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item> <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Status</item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

> CM\Shippingbar\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Status.php

```
<?php

namespace CM\Shippingbar\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

class Status implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{
/**
 * Options getter
 *
 * @return array
 */
   public function toOptionArray()
   {
       return [['value' => 1, 'label' => __('Enable')], ['value' => 0, 'label' => __('Disable')]];
   }
}
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Error comes : ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getAvailableStatuses() on null in

Comment: Have you add `getAvailableStatuses()` in your model file?

Comment: s i added in my model file

Comment: can you share your updated code in your question?

Comment: i was update my code in above question

Comment: You have just copy and paste my code. you have add `getAvailableStatuses()` function in your model file.

Comment: can you share your `CM\Shippingbar\Model\Shippingbar.php` code?

Comment: please refer a updated question in above

Comment: https://prnt.sc/n6dxf5

Comment: I have updated `CM\Shippingbar\Model\Status.php` file change your Status.php file. and let me know.

Comment: Still status label shows as 0 or 1 https://prnt.sc/n6e68t

Comment: Have you flushed cache?
In the database `Status` column what value have you stored?

Comment: i flushed a cache and my db stored value https://prnt.sc/n6edlb

Comment: It is working fine in my module

Comment: You can try with this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/217444/how-to-display-yes-no-values-in-admin-grid-magento2?noredirect=1&lq=1
It might work for you.

Comment: i will try and update u

Comment: above link help me solve out this problem thanks

Comment: You can acept as answer if you found my answer is useful to you so it is also useful to other user.

Comment: i  edited a  worked answer accept the updated answer @Chirag

Comment: Thank you so much for you appreciation :)

Answer (score 2):

try this way... 
and shippingbar_post_listing.xml in my code replace

```
<column name="status">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options" xsi:type="object">CM\Shippingbar\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Status</item><item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">60</item>
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item> <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Status</item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
```

and **CM\Shippingbar\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Status.php** code this way..

```
<?php

namespace CM\Shippingbar\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

class Status implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{
/**
 * Options getter
 *
 * @return array
 */
   public function toOptionArray()
   {
       return [['value' => 1, 'label' => __('Enable')], ['value' => 0, 'label' => __('Disable')]];
   }
}
```

Comment: In which file @rakesh

Comment: its not working rakesh

Comment: you have my code use and replace it?

Comment: S I did it, its again show status '0' or '1'

Comment: https://prnt.sc/n6dyv9  i used it but it replicate same https://prnt.sc/n6dzm6

Comment: @divyasekar my code is corrected yesterday , but you have not implement correctly

Comment: no @rakesh i implement a code what you said exactly but its not happens

Comment: ok no problem @divyasekar

Comment: its shows  a label after using this pathu <item name="options" xsi:type="object">CM\Shippingbar\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Status</item>  only @rakesh

Comment: now i replace  this path  <item name="options" xsi:type="object">CM\Shippingbar\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Status</item> with  <item name="options" xsi:type="object">CM\Shippingbar\Model\Status</item> its not shown label

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91895/discussion-between-rakesh-donga-and-divya-sekar).